# react native and setting up the gmail api

Tags: objective-c, react-native, gmail-api

I am having trouble setting up the gmail api. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Instruction:

```
Run the following command to download the library using git:

git clone --recursive https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client.git
```

In the command line I navigated to the root directory of my project and ran that command.

```
Open Xcode and create a new workspace named "Quickstart".

Using File > Add Files to "Quickstart"..., add the following project to the workspace that you cloned in the previous step:
google-api-objectivec-client/Source/GTLCore.xcodeproj
```

I did not create a new workspace I simply used the existing one. I clicked file > Add files to "Inbox" and added the `GTLCore.xcodeproj`

```
Create a new iOS > Application > Single View Application project named "QuickstartApp", with the organization "com.example". Set the Language to Objective-C, and when saving the project set the Add to and Group fields to "Quickstart".
```

Since I already have a project I did not do this step.

```
Add the following frameworks and libraries to the project's Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries section:
GTL.framework (from GTLiOSCore target)
```

I clicked on my Inbox project, selected build phases and added the GTL.framework.

```
Change the following Build Settings:
Add the flag GTL_BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK=1 to Preprocessor Macros.
```

I clicked on my Inbox project, clicked build settings, searched for preprocessor macros and added that line of code.

```
Add the file google-api-objectivec-client/Source/OAuth2/Touch/GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib to the project's Supporting Files group.
```

I selected inboxTests > supporting files, right click add files to inbox
however the file is not in that location it is located in

```
/google-api-objectivec-client/Deps/gtm-oauth2/Source/Touch/GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib
```

Add the following files to the QuickstartApp group:

```
google-api-objectivec-client/Source/Services/Gmail/Generated/GTLGmail_Sources.m

google-api-objectivec-client/Source/Services/Gmail/Generated/GTLGmail.h
```

I right click on my inbox folder and selected '`add files to inbox`' both of these files were added in my inbox folder.

now at this point try to compile but get an error `'GTLObject.h'file not found`

This file is located in the GTLCore.xcodeproj that was added in step 3. Every time I add one of these files it asks for another.

step 4: I created my own files

gmail.h

```
#ifndef gmail_h
#define gmail_h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "GTL/GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
#import "GTLGmail.h"

@interface gmail : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) GTLServiceGmail *service;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *output;

@end

#endif /* gmail_h */
```

copy and pasted into a new file
gmail.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "gmail.h"

static NSString *const kKeychainItemName = @"Gmail API";
static NSString *const kClientID = @"this is my key";

@implementation gmail

@synthesize service = _service;
@synthesize output = _output;

// When the view loads, create necessary subviews, and initialize the Gmail API service.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Create a UITextView to display output.
  self.output = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
  self.output.editable = false;
  self.output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0);
  self.output.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
  [self.view addSubview:self.output];

  // Initialize the Gmail API service & load existing credentials from the keychain if available.
  self.service = [[GTLServiceGmail alloc] init];
  self.service.authorizer =
  [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                        clientID:kClientID
                                                    clientSecret:nil];
}

// When the view appears, ensure that the Gmail API service is authorized, and perform API calls.
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if (!self.service.authorizer.canAuthorize) {
    // Not yet authorized, request authorization by pushing the login UI onto the UI stack.
    [self presentViewController:[self createAuthController] animated:YES completion:nil];

  } else {
    [self fetchLabels];
  }
}

// Construct a query and get a list of labels from the user's gmail. Display the
// label name in the UITextView
- (void)fetchLabels {
  self.output.text = @"Getting labels...";
  GTLQueryGmail *query = [GTLQueryGmail queryForUsersLabelsList];
  [self.service executeQuery:query
                    delegate:self
           didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
}

- (void)displayResultWithTicket:(GTLServiceTicket *)ticket
             finishedWithObject:(GTLGmailListLabelsResponse *)labelsResponse
                          error:(NSError *)error {
  if (error == nil) {
    NSMutableString *labelString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    if (labelsResponse.labels.count > 0) {
      [labelString appendString:@"Labels:\n"];
      for (GTLGmailLabel *label in labelsResponse.labels) {
        [labelString appendFormat:@"%@\n", label.name];
      }
    } else {
      [labelString appendString:@"No labels found."];
    }
    self.output.text = labelString;
  } else {
    [self showAlert:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
  }
}


// Creates the auth controller for authorizing access to Gmail API.
- (GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)createAuthController {
  GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *authController;
  NSArray *scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopeGmailReadonly, nil];
  authController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc]
                    initWithScope:[scopes componentsJoinedByString:@" "]
                    clientID:kClientID
                    clientSecret:nil
                    keychainItemName:kKeychainItemName
                    delegate:self
                    finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
  return authController;
}

// Handle completion of the authorization process, and update the Gmail API
// with the new credentials.
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
      finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
                 error:(NSError *)error {
  if (error != nil) {
    [self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
    self.service.authorizer = nil;
  }
  else {
    self.service.authorizer = authResult;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  }
}

// Helper for showing an alert
- (void)showAlert:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message {
  UIAlertView *alert;
  alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                     message:message
                                    delegate:nil
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states that *"the static library target also creates a folder with the library's headers to drag into your target's sources"*. The corresponding directory contains only one header file `GTLDefines.h` and it apparently makes no reference to other required ones such as `GTLObject.h`, nor is there a folder that contains only header files. I think it is necessary to manually add references to 
other required header files such as Objects/GTLObject.h into the app project.

Try also to look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343785/google-cloud-endpoints-linking-ios-client-issues). It states here that he imported headers from the GTL.proj to his project. These include files like `GTLBase64.h`, `GTLBatchQuery.h`, `GTLBatchResult.h`. Without the headers, he gets the error **"GTLObject.h file not found."** on the import statement.

Comment: Thank you very much, your advice and link was very helpful. I Decided to go with Node Js to handle the api.